# React array.splice calls the method several times in a row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Inside the reducer, I'm calling the reoder method. 
Inside the method, I'm trying to re-arrange the element and move the element at the startIndex to the endIndex.

However, when I put the debugger, whenever it reaches the line with

```
const [removed] = ...
```

It goes back to the function call and calls/renders reoder function several times. After that, tempArray is empty even though cards array is never empty.

If I remove that line, tempArray isn't empty and is the same as cards array. However, with that line the tempArray is always empty.

Also,

```
    const reoder = (cards, startIndex, endIndex) => {
      debugger
      const tempArray = Array.from(cards)
      const [removed] = tempArray.splice(startIndex)
      console.log(tempArray)
    }
```

Here is my cards array.

```
  mainPlayerCards: [
    {
      id: 0,
      value: "A"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      value: "B"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: "C"
    }
  ],
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm not too sure what's happening up there.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you're doing this on the reducer?

Comment: When `splice` is called like `arr.splice(0)` it empties the `arr` array. You may want to read the documentation on `splice`. This has nothing to do with what you write in the question's title. Did you intend to write `.splice(startIndex, 1)`... with the second argument? Or maybe `.splice(startIndex, endIndex-startIndex)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `1` (number of items to delete) as a second argument to `tempArray.splice(startIndex)` call:

```js
const reoder = (cards, startIndex, endIndex) => {
  const tempArray = Array.from(cards)
  const [removed] = tempArray.splice(startIndex, 1)
  tempArray.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
  console.log(tempArray);
  return tempArray;
};

reoder([
    {
      id: 0,
      value: "A"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      value: "B"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: "C"
    }
  ], 0,1);
```

Comment: Wow, I should've read the documentation more clearly! Thanks!